# disable only owner window in wpf

Tags: c#, wpf

I have a application in which there is a window (let's say W1) I want it not to block the application processing while it is opened. I have achieved this using `W1.show()`. There is another window (W2) which is opened from this window.

I want it's behavior to be something like a modal so that it disables the parent window W1 with the exception that it **must not** disable the remaining application.

In Short:
when W2 is opened

- application continues its operation
- only W1 gets disabled

I tried

```
        W1.IsEnabled = false;
        W2.Show();
        W1.IsEnabled = true;
```

it moves focus to W2 when it is opened and remaining application also continues it's operation but I am still able to use W1 which is incorrect

If I use

`W2.ShowDialog()`

then the entire application is blocked. Is there some method through which only the parent Window (/owner) can be disabled?

Comment: What operations in w1... manually disable with IsEnabled , and the re-enabled it when w2 has been closed.

Comment: That's can be an option if i get no other solution but 1) there are too many controls in it  2) trying to click on it should not move focus to it (just like opening a modal Window).

Comment: What operations need to keep running?

Comment: actually it's a designing application. The user should be able to continue designing in the main window (not W1)

Answer (score 1):

This should answer your question:

```
private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    W2.Owner = W1;
    W1.IsHitTestVisible = false;
    W2.Closing += W2_Closing;
    W2.Show();
}

private void W2_Closing(object sender, CancelEventArgs e)
{
    W1.IsHitTestVisible = true;
}
```

Comment: This is good. There are few more points
1) The window W1 still gets focus when we click on it
2) If possible, trying to click on W1 after W2 is opened, W2 should give the same effect/animation that we get when we have ope/save as dialog open in different applications and we try to use the mainwindow

Comment: Not by my side. Check it by yourself: `W1.GotFocus += W1_GotFocus;`. Have you done it as I have posted with `Closing` event handler??

Comment: yes, I have tested the code you wrote in post, but haven't added focus code to it. let me try it

Comment: Actually this answer is just the answer to you question. Main window is accessible all the time and W1 is inaccessible till W2 is opend. Concerning the styling - it is another question, more broad. For disabled look out you still can aditionally use `W1.IsEnabled = false;` and in event handler `W1.IsEnabled = true;`

Answer (score 0):

Consider 3 windows `w1`,`w2`,`w3`. `W1` and `W2` are shown initially. And from `W1` you call  `W3.ShowDialog()`, this will disable both `w1` and `w2` since they are both running on the same UI thread .I believe your requirement is to disable only one of `w1` or `w2`. (In this case lets say you want to enable `w2` and disable `w1`)

for this you need launch the `w2` from a different thread with STA behavior, That way it will prevent `w2` from getting disabled

```
Thread newWindowThread = new Thread(new ThreadStart(ThreadStartingPoint));
newWindowThread.SetApartmentState(ApartmentState.STA);
newWindowThread.IsBackground = true;
newWindowThread.Start();



private void ThreadStartingPoint()
      {
         Window3 tempWindow = new Window3();
         tempWindow.Show();
         System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.Run();
      }
```